# Proving a property holds during the entirety of the mating ritual.

Tags: graph-theory

The question:

We define the following derived variables for the Mating Ritual:

> q(B)=j, where j is the rank of the girl that boy B is courting. That is to say, boy B is always courting the j<sup>th</sup> girl on his list.

> r(G) is the number of boys that girl G has rejected.

Show that S remains the same from one day to the next in the Mating Ritual where S is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8u58.jpg).

I am having trouble proving that S remains the same during the entirety of the mating ritual. I can see that on i<sup>th</sup> day, the value of Σq(B) increases by the number of boys who have been rejected on the (i-1)<sup>th</sup> day.
Therefore, S would be the same for the totality of the mating ritual only if the number of boys rejected on the i<sup>th</sup> day is twice the number of boys rejected on the (i-1)<sup>th</sup> day but this is not always true. Where am I wrong?
What would be a good strategy to prove this?

Comment: It's better to type out everything rather than using pictures so the post is more searchable. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Have you considered saying "Gale-Shapley algorithm" rather than "mating ritual", which is much more well-known terminology as well as being a lot less creepy?

Comment: Anyway, you've figured out how much $\sum_{B \in \text{Boys}} q(B)$ increases on the $i^{\text{th}}$ day. How much does $\sum_{G \in \text{Girls}} r(G)$ increase on the $i^{\text{th}}$ day?

Comment: @MishaLavrov $\sum r(G)$ increases by the number of girls who had no suitor on the $i^{th}$ day. That is not necessarily the same as the number of boys rejected on the $(i-1)^{th}$ day.

Comment: I think you are just wrong about that. For each girl $G$, $r(G)$ increases by $1$ if she rejects a boy, not if she had no suitor.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Regarding my previous comment, I meant that the number of boys rejected someday is equal to the number of girls who had no suitor on that day.

Comment: Also, $\sum q(B)$ someday - $\sum q(B)$ on the previous day = Number of boys rejected on the previous day.                                                                    
And, $\sum r(G)$ someday - $\sum r(G)$ up till the previous day = Number of boys rejected on that day.                                                                          


If I am correct so far, then S would remain the same on subsequent days if the RHS of the above 2 equations is the same, but I don't think that is always true.